# Sabre: Bargain Finder Max RESTful endpoint, baggage related questions

Tags: api, rest, sabre

*The text below needs to be treated as a question, not as an explanation.*

**To get the maximum information about the baggage, the following request parameters are needed, am I correct?**

```
TravelPreferences.Baggage: {
  Description: true, // to receive the baggage description as text
  CarryOnInfo: true, // to receive the info about carry-on baggage (hand baggage)
  RequestType: 'C',  // to receive the info about paid baggage (charge)
}
```

**In response, the information related to baggages can be found in the property passengerInfoList->passengerInfo->baggageInformation.**

Where, the value of the property "provisionType" indicates the baggage type and also if the baggage is included, or it needs to be paid.

The most common provisionType values seems to be:

```
A = Free hold baggage;
C = Paid hold baggage;
B = Free hand baggage;
CC = Paid hand baggage.
```

If the baggage is free (provisionType: A, B), there is a property named "allowance", by using allowance ref id, we can get more information about baggage allowance: number of baggage, text descriptions (the weight, size).
I do not understand why the Sabre API give us information about baggage where the pieceCount is 0, or pieceCount property does not exist (means no baggage available). Can you explain why?

If the baggage is paid (provisionType, C, CC), there is a property named "charge" (id), where we can get the information about paid baggage: the price for 1 baggage, and also the text description about the baggage.

Does the "firstPiece" and "lastPiece" property indicates the number of baggage for which this tariff is applied for?

How often in your practice the baggage price is indicated in another currency than USD (equivalentCurrency)?

Can you explain what does mean "noChargeNotAvailable"?

**Should we display to the client the baggage information from Bargain Finder Max response, or there is a better alternative for getting the information about baggage?**